# Suggest architecture pattern for generic services

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We are connecting to different services describing some Stock Tase information.
For now there are three services. Each of the services returns information a different way: XML, Json, Pipe separated string. The number of services can grow in near future.

I'd like to implement this the most flexible way, with maximum abstraction. The only pattern (from those which I am familiar with) is the factory-pattern or the abstract factory. Maybe even the strategy-pattern is an option here.

Maybe you can suggest better implementation way?

Summary:

```
StockInformationParser 
-> Connects to Service 1 || Service 2 || or Service N 
-> Parses and analyses information
-> returns StockInformationInfo.
```

Comment: I would go with Factory pattern wich accepts standard format, then adapter pattern to standardize each different service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that all of these external services ultimately map to one and the same domain model.

In that case, you could:

- create an internal service with operations that can be consumed by your client(s), with data contracts optimized for these clients.
- the internal service uses underlying repositories and domain model.
- repositories are responsible for abstracting the way the data is retrieved. Internally they get the data from the external providers and map these to your domain objects. You could write a provider for each of the external services and use those in your repository. If an external service is added, you only have to add a new provider and add it to the repository logic.

Personally I like IoC and so I would create interfaces for every component and inject concrete instances; which makes it even more flexible and testable.

Comment: I like Also Ioc and Dependency injection working together , But unfortunately I can't see it working with my problem ,probably because of poor Architecture understanding...

Comment: For example, you have an IExternalDataProvider that defines operations you need to interact with the external services, like a Get operation. Then for each external service you write a concrete implementation, like XmlExternalDataProvider implements IExternalDataProvider by calling the external service, parsing the XML and returning domain objects; etc.

Comment: Could you please point me to some short example of your approach.

Comment: I don't have a short example, but maybe http://tinyurl.com/d99w8rl can give some inspiration because it handles a lot of concepts that might be interesting.

Comment: It depends on you requirements of course, so it's up to you to decide what concepts you want to adopt.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your situation, I suggest you should apply more design patterns and it should combine together for resolving your problem as below:
1. Facade pattern : It work as a contact point class to reduce the complexity when connect many services.

1. For each result return each service, you may be need a parsing engine with the same method but each format Json, Xml, rss, ... same method but different format so you should apply strategy pattern to resolve.
2. Each service will need a scheme factory to connection so abstract factory or factory design pattern are appropriate.
3. The last thing, you will want result are abstraction to easy to change or extent later you can apply proxy pattern at here.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply , I will investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

I will have little different approach. How about creating a database and fill it with these services and then you can easily query database in favorite SQL and use Group By, Order and Joins.

Advantages are,

- No need to reinvent query adapter, after all you need to query.
- No need to worry about different format, once fetched data stays as row
  in database.
- Improved caching In case of service failure or connection issue you can still see past data.

Comment: At the end , the results are saved to DataBase... but what I am trying to build is Analysis Infrastructure , we are getting Some info from some services , then applying our own Analysis system , and results are stored to Database

Comment: I am talking about storing info straight out of Service after parsing but before applying any analysis, just raw table dump. Your service returns Some sort of rows right?